# Getting value of a field in a nesting relation

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables with a relation. The find method works very well without problem, i get all the fields that i want between both tables. The delete method work fine also.

But i want to add a validation before delete the record, verifiying  the relation with the secondary table, if the relation exists can't delete the record.

**My Tables**:

- invoices: id, company_id, number, invoice_date
- invoice_numbers: id, company_id, number
- companies: id, name

**My Models**:

**Invoice**:

```
class Invoice extends AppModel
{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Company',
        'InvoiceNumber' => array(
            'className' => 'InvoiceNumber',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'InvoiceNumber.company_id = Invoice.company_id',
                'InvoiceNumber.number = Invoice.number',
            ),
            'type' => 'left',
            'fields' => array(
                'FacturaNumero.id',
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

**InvoiceNumber**:

```
class InvoiceNumber extends AppModel
{
    public $hasOne = array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'className' => 'Invoice',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Invoice.company_id = InvoiceNumber.company_id',
                'Invoice.number = InvoiceNumber.number',
            ),
            'type' => 'left',
            'fields' => array(
                'Invoice.invoice_date',
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

**My Controller** (delete Method):

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->InvoiceNumber->id = $id;

    if (!$this->InvoiceNumber->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid Record.');
    }

    /**
     * I want to add a validation here if field invoide_date is not null, by example
     * but this dont work, because get the first value in the invoice table.
    */  
    if (!empty($this->InvoiceNumber->Invoice->field('invoice_date')) {
        throw new NotFoundException('I Cant Delete this record.');
    } else {
        $this->InvoiceNumber->delete();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misunderstanding here is that when you write

```
$this->InvoiceNumber->Invoice
```

you are just accesing a generic Invoice Model Object and not the Invoice of that specific InvoiceNumber

I think that you just need to change your code in

```
$InvoiceNumber = $this->InvoiceNumber->read();
if (!empty($InvoiceNumber['Invoice'])) {
    // ...
}
```

but maybe this is not the best way: I think that a cleaner approach could be to do the validation in the InvoiceNumber `beforeDelete()` method

PS: sorry for the typos. Now should be correct

Comment: Now i used the [beforeDelete()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforedelete) callback example, but i dont know if this is the better way.